# trigger alarms based on strings in log file

Tags: log-files, zabbix

I've installed zabbix 2.4.5 on my ubuntu linux server.
I have 2 remote servers configured, lets called the relevant one foo.

i want to monitor a log file for a specific text, and if it finds it to alarm me.

so first I created an item

[image: item creation]

then I created a trigger:

[image: trigger creation]

in general I'm trying to find lines with the text "in previous game Object"

now when I check the status of the trigger, i get "not supported".

[image: not supported]

any ideas why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last screenshot that you have is that of an item being "not supported", rather than a trigger. If you hover over the red cross on the right side, you should see the reason why the item is not supported.

According to https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent, the log[] item must be configured as an active check, so the type should be "Zabbix agent (active)" instead of "Zabbix agent".